# Google Analytics 4 Events Report filtered by custom parameter

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am logging my custom events with an additional parameter called "Tag". The events are logged correctly, and I can see the Tags there.

I want to create a report for one single event type filtered by the Tag value.

For example, my custom events are named "event_1" and "event_2". For "event_1" I have "tag_a" and "tag_b", and for "event_2" I have "tag_c" and "tag_d".

When I go to Engagement > Events, I see the count for both events there. And when I click "event_1", I go the individual event report.

On the right-hand side of the page, I see a panel "Events in last 30 minutes", and there I can enter "Tag" as a parameter, and I see the count for "tag_a" and "tag_b". This is exactly what I need, but not just for the last 30 minutes, but for the date range that I enter on the dropdown on top right.

Can anyone please help me on how to achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup custom dimensions in GA4. You can do this by accessing the right menu in the Admin Panel:

Admin >> Custom Dimensions

Google also has some [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccreate-a-user-scoped-custom-dimension) on how to do it. Make sure you scope it correctly: either user or event.

When you set up the dimensions, remember there is a delay before you can use it in your reports.

If you are leveraging Looker Studio to do reporting, make sure you refresh your data connection so the new dimensions will show.